# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'result' property from 'IDBRequest': The request has not finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexeddb

I'm binding data to 3 dropdowns by calling a method from another file of javascript. The data source of dropdown loading from IndexedDB.
Data binding JS,

```
function bindStateData(){
     getMstStates("#state");
     getMstStates("#drstate");
     getMstStates("#cstate");
   }
```

Database manager js,

```
function getMstStates(state) {
    var request = indexedDB.open('AppDatabase', '3')
    request.onsuccess = function (e) {
        var dbInstance = e.target.result;
        let transaction = dbInstance.transaction("MstStates", "readonly");
        const statesDetailsStore = transaction.objectStore("MstStates");
        stateData = statesDetailsStore.getAll();
        stateData.onsuccess = function () {
            var MstStatesMap = new Object();
            var len = stateData.result.length,
            i;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                MstStatesMap[i] = {};
                MstStatesMap[i].StateId = stateData.result[i].StateId;
                MstStatesMap[i].StateName = stateData.result[i].StateName;
            }
            callBackOptionItems(MstStatesMap, state);
        }
        stateData.onerror = function () {
            console.log('getMstStates : ' + e);
        }
     }
    request.onerror = function (e) { console.log('getMstStates : ' + e); }
}

function callBackOptionItems(MstOptionMap, objID) {
    for (var j in MstOptionMap) {
        var k, v
        var tem = 0;
        for (var i in MstOptionMap[j]) {
            if (tem == 0) {
                k = MstOptionMap[j][i]
            } else {
                v = MstOptionMap[j][i];
            }
            tem++
        }
        var el = $(objID);
        $(el).append('<option value="' + k + '">' + v + '</option>');

    }
    if (objID == '#select-history') {
        $("#select-history").append('<option value="4">Other</option>');
    }
}
```

When I tried to loading data I got the following error,

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'result' property from 'IDBRequest': The request has not finished.
    at IDBRequest.stateData.onsuccess
```

The same code logic was written in WebSQL, it was running properly, but unfortunately from iOS 13 version websql support has been revoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. The main culprit line is,

```
var len = stateData.result.length;
```

The correct code is as follows,

```
    var _request = statesDetailsStore.getAll();
    _request.onsuccess = function (event) {
        var MstStatesMap = new Object();
        var stateData = event.target.result;
    }
```